# Why doesnt this .every() method work here?

Tags: javascript, methods

```js
const allEvens = (arr) =>allEvens.every(item => return item %2 ===0)
}
```

Hey, so im trying here to check if every number is even, and if its not it should return false. But now Ive spent almost 2 hours trying to understand why this doesnt work for me, trying to change some things but none of them worked. Can someone give me any clue where's the problem here ? Thank you very much!

Comment: That is a syntax error. `return` must be used in a statement block. Without block you should also skip the `return` keyword.

Comment: If this is your actual code, remove the return, or put `item %2 ===0` inside brackets

Answer (score 2):

You have to remove the `return` keyword to make it return (item % 2 === 0) expression. But if you want to keep that return, you have to put the body of function inside curly braces.

Answer (score 0):

When you omit "{...}" from the body of an arrow function, it automatically indicates that you want to directly return the content (the result of `item % 2 === 0` in this case). So the following should help solve the issue:

```js
const allEvens = (arr) => allEvens.every((item) => item % 2 === 0);
console.log(allEvens([12, 6, 8])) // true
console.log(allEvens([12, 6, 8, 1])) // false
```